# using a dll in ezcad with c++

Tags: c++, dll

I have one dll explicitly link and I would like to use.

I create this code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <MarkEzdDll.h>
#include < TCHAR.H >
#include<HLink.h>
typedef int (__stdcall *Thiago)();

int main()

{


HINSTANCE hEzdDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("C:\\Users\\Thiago\\Desktop\\DLL\\Debug\\MarkEzd.dll"));
Thiago lmc1_Initial = (Thiago)GetProcAddress(hEzdDLL , "lmc1_Initial");
lmc1_Initial();

}
```

But not fuction, the error this:

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x10007f76 (MarkEzd.dll) in DLL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

what I do?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the return error code, if it's `NULL` you have an error.

According to [these sources](https://code.google.com/p/fop3d/source/browse/trunk/Debug/MarkEzdDll.h?spec=svn10&r=10) (and assuming that's the same library you're using), the signature is actually:

```
typedef int (*LMC1_INITIAL)(TCHAR* strEzCadPath, BOOL bTestMode, HWND hOwenWnd);
```